# How to get type of Julia variable?

Tags: julia

So I try to read simple Julia array related [code](https://github.com/SimonDanisch/SchroedingersSmoke.jl/blob/master/src/MatlabPort.jl#L81). i try to understand a type `lambda` gets.

```
lambda = floatVar .* (Array_Int_3_A .^ 2 .+ Array_Int_3_B .^ 2 .+ Array_Int_3_C .^ 2);
```

Would turn into

```
lambda[i] = floatVar * (Array_Int_3_A[i]^2 + Array_Int_3_B[i]^2 + ...)
```

Yet Array_Int_3_A is array of 3 ints so lambda would also be Array of array of Ints of size 3? is there some tool or util in Julia to show function variable types? And btw is there a tool to show code using `.` as more traditional array styled code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the type of any Julia object `o` by `typeof(o)`.

```
help?> typeof
search: typeof typejoin TypeError

  typeof(x)

  Get the concrete type of x.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> a = 1//2;

  julia> typeof(a)
  Rational{Int64}

  julia> M = [1 2; 3.5 4];

  julia> typeof(M)
  Array{Float64,2}
```

In your line of code all dots just mean "apply the operation element-wise". Therefore the types (and sizes) don't change.

Also, just to be precise here, `Array{Int,3}` doesn't mean "array of 3 integers" but instead "3-dimensional array", which can have arbitrary extent in either of those dimensions. To get the extent or size of the array you can use `size(x)`.